# How to change the background color in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to change the paper color(background color) in tikz class kindly help me to change color

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,amsthm,geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pagecolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pagecolor,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text}
% tight page
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
        % outer circle
            \draw[line width=2 mm,color=black,fill=white!10] circle[radius=7cm];
        % outer text
            \path[
                postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.1ex,
                        text along path,
                        text format delimiters={|}{|},
                        text={%
                            |\Huge\bfseries\color{black}|
                          name name {\textbullet} name {\textbullet} name name name name name
                        },
                        text align=fit to path,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
             (0:6.2cm) arc (0:360:6.2cm);
\draw[line width=2 mm,color=black,fill=white!10] circle[radius=5.8cm];
% central text
\node[color=Brown3] at (0, 1){\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{14}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Add `\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}` and

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!45}, show background rectangle]
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,latexsym,amssymb,amsthm,geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pagecolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pagecolor,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}
% tight page
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={fill=olive!45}, show background rectangle]
        % outer circle
            \draw[line width=2 mm,color=black,fill=white!10] circle[radius=7cm];
        % outer text
            \path[
                postaction={
                    decoration={raise=.1ex,
                        text along path,
                        text format delimiters={|}{|},
                        text={%
                            |\Huge\bfseries\color{black}|
                          name name {\textbullet} name {\textbullet} name name name name name
                        },
                        text align=fit to path,
                        reverse path
                    },
                    decorate
                }
            ]
             (0:6.2cm) arc (0:360:6.2cm);
\draw[line width=2 mm,color=black,fill=white!10] circle[radius=5.8cm];
% central text
\node[color=Brown3] at (0, 1){\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This works when I am compiling a standalone tikzpicture. But when I include it another document using \includestandalone from standalone package, it does not work. Any solution for that?

Comment: @GautamSreekumar: you have to be more specific about “does not work” to get a decent answer to your question. Your issue probably has nothing to do with the backgrounds library to tikz, but is about your setup of standalone. So best to devise your own MWE and ask a separate question

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, my bad. I tried to reproduce and figured out my mistake in the process. By "does not work", I meant that the background color was missing when I imported such a figure using `\includestandalone` command in a main document. I figured that it was due to missing `\usetikzlibrary{background}`  in the main document. I think I missed out this warning on Overleaf but saw it on TeXstudio.